# Why $ G/F $ acts irreducibly on $ A $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a soluble group and $ A $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Then $ A $ is an elementary abelian group of prime power order. Suppose $ N $ is the Fitting subgroup of $ G $. Then $ N = O_{p}(G) $ and $ A \leq Z(N) $. Let $ F/N = O_{p^{\prime}}(G/N) $. And so, i show $ A \leq Z(F) $. Why $ G/F $ acts irreducibly on $ A $ ? What is the irreducible action ?

Comment: Because $A$ is a minimal normal subgroup. If it acted reducibly then there would be a smaller normal subgroup. The action is by conjugation.

Comment: Is there a reference for irreducible action ?

Comment: @DerekHolt I thought but did not understand if $ G/F $ acted reducibly then there would be a smaller normal subgroup. Can explain, please ?

Comment: This is just definition. First note that the action of $G$ on $A$ is by conjugation. Since $A \le Z(F)$, the action of $F$ on $A$ is trivial, so we get an induced action of $G/F$ on $A$. To say the action is reducible means that there is a proper nontrivial subgroup $B$ of $A$ such that $g^{-1}Ag = A$ for all $g \in G$. But then $B$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ smaller than $A$, contradicting the minimality of $A$.

Comment: @DerekHolt How to conclude $ A \leq Z(G) $ and $ \vert A \vert  $ is a prime number ? For the answer, is it true that say, the action of $ G $ on $  A $ is irreducible, since the action of $ G/N $ on $ A $ is irreducible, then trivial subgroups are $ G $-invariant subgroups of $ A $, then $ A \leq Z(G) $ ?